# How to convert Relativelayout To PDF Then Print and Download

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, pdf

I tried some code but couldn't work here is my XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#D2D3D5"
tools:context=".View.Dashbord.AllotmentDoc">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fulldoc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/toipbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:text="@string/tcb_title"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="@string/karjaloy"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
                android:text="@string/dhaka"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

             </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rightnav"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
                android:text="@string/date"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
                android:text="@string/_01_01_21"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="SmallSp" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/rightnav"
            android:id="@+id/rightnavroll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
                    android:text="ক্রমিক নং: "
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
                    android:text="01"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:ignore="SmallSp" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toipbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:text="@string/aggrement"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/tableheader"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text="@string/product_name"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text="@string/products_quantity"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text="@string/mesurment"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text="@string/total_price"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />


    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/onion"
            android:padding="3dip" />

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text="@string/_2000_kg"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text="25.00"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text="50000"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/onion"
            android:padding="3dip" />

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text="@string/_2000_kg"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text="@string/_20_00"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text="40000"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:padding="3dip" />

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:padding="3dip" />

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text=" "
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text="@string/intotal"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/calibri_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/table_border"
            android:text="@string/_90000"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:text="@string/aggrement1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableheader"
    android:id="@+id/aggrement"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottombar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/aggrement"
    android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/nd_sign"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/office_prodhan"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/signofbuyer"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>


 </RelativeLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pdfsection"
    android:layout_below="@id/fulldoc"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="NotSibling">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/printpdf"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/editbox"
        android:text="@string/prints_pdf"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:layout_height="45sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/downloadpdf"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/editbox"
        android:text="@string/download_pdf"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:layout_height="45sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gotopayment"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pdfsection"
    android:background="@drawable/editbox"
    android:text="@string/go_to_payment"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:layout_width="150sp"
    android:layout_height="45sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Here is my Java Code I was trying. I try This library: https://github.com/Gkemon/Android-XML-to-PDF-Generator

But Couldn't work.

```
 package com.example.tcbmobileapp.View.Dashbord;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.example.tcbmobileapp.R;
import com.example.tcbmobileapp.View.Payment.PaymentOption;
import com.gkemon.XMLtoPDF.PdfGenerator;
import com.gkemon.XMLtoPDF.PdfGeneratorListener;
import com.gkemon.XMLtoPDF.model.FailureResponse;
import com.gkemon.XMLtoPDF.model.SuccessResponse;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class AllotmentDoc extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView printPDF, downloadPDF, gotoPayment;
RelativeLayout pdfmain;
String str;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_allotment_doc);


    printPDF = findViewById(R.id.printpdf);
    downloadPDF = findViewById(R.id.downloadpdf);
    gotoPayment = findViewById(R.id.gotopayment);
    pdfmain = findViewById(R.id.fulldoc);




    gotoPayment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(AllotmentDoc.this, PaymentOption.class));
        }
    });

    pdfmain = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.fulldoc);

    printPDF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context= AllotmentDoc.this;
            PdfGenerator.getBuilder()
                    .setContext(context)
                    .fromLayoutXMLSource()
                    .fromLayoutXML(R.layout.activity_allotment_doc, R.layout.activity_allotment_doc)
                    .setDefaultPageSize(PdfGenerator.PageSize.A4)
                    .setFileName("Allotment_PaperPDF")
                    /* It is file name */
                    .setFolderName("TCBMobileApp")
                    .openPDFafterGeneration(true)
                    /* It true then the generated pdf will be shown after generated. */
                    .build(new PdfGeneratorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(FailureResponse failureResponse) {
                            super.onFailure(failureResponse);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void showLog(String log) {
                            super.showLog(log);
                            /*It shows logs of events inside the pdf generation process*/
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(SuccessResponse response) {
                            super.onSuccess(response);
                            /* If PDF is generated successfully then you will find SuccessResponse
                             * which holds the PdfDocument,File and path (where generated pdf is 
 stored)*/

                        }
                    });

        }
    });

    }

  }
```

Basically, I want to print my layout (`R.id.fulldoc`) only I won't include the rest inside my pdf so how can I do that. I want to show my pdf so that users can view and also user can download it using the download button.

Here is the image link : [image: My layout looks like and I want to work with that button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/Gkemon/Android-XML-to-PDF-Generator) to make it easy to do within a few lines of code. Here I'm seeing that you are inputting the full layout but you need to just input the specific view instead only like -

```
  PdfGenerator.getBuilder()
                        .setContext(context)
                        .fromViewIDSource()
                        .fromViewID(activity,R.id.fulldoc) //The specifi view id you want to print
                        .setDefaultPageSize(PdfGenerator.PageSize.A4)
                        .setFileName("Allotment_PaperPDF")
                        .setFolderName("TCBMobileApp")
                        .build(new PdfGeneratorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(FailureResponse failureResponse) {
                            super.onFailure(failureResponse);
                        }
            
                        @Override
                        public void onStartPDFGeneration() {
                            /*When PDF generation begins to start*/
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinishPDFGeneration() {
                            /*When PDF generation is finished*/
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void showLog(String log) {
                            super.showLog(log);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(SuccessResponse response) {
                            super.onSuccess(response);
                        }
                    });
```

For more insight, please see my [doc](https://github.com/Gkemon/Android-XML-to-PDF-Generator#from-view-ids-) which is related to your problem.

First of all make sure that you are using my latest version `v.2.0` where I fixed some bug and `Java version 1.8` in your app level gradle -

```
 implementation 'com.github.Gkemon:XML-to-PDF-generator:2.0'
```

To get an example please see [here](https://github.com/Gkemon/Android-XML-to-PDF-Generator#-installation).

Comment: How Can I View created PDF?

Comment: @KayesFahim please see my edited answer. Implement the listener and in on success callback you will get a response where you will find the generated file's path and you can deal with this path as you want. And with in a few days, I will try to make a new feature to open the generated file. Then I will let you know.